# parsing json into a variable without knowing incoming fields

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to parse json using javascript without knowing the incoming fields. I seem to have figured that out but trying to map it to a set format I need, is not working.

```
var json = '{"new_records":"1022", "updated_records":"546565", 
       "changed_records":"546566", "deleted_records":"122345", 
       "missing_records":"78"}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
console.log(Object.values(obj));
for (var p in obj) {
 console.log(p);
}
```

So I will not know if the json is an array, an object or both. What I would like to do next is parse or push the json key and value pairs to a format as follows:

```
line = "measurement" + " ,new_records="1022" + ",updated_records="546565" + ",changed_records="546566" + ",deleted_records="122345" + ",missing_records="78"  + " " + Date.now() * 1000000;
```

As you can see in the above, the fields and values are placed in the above as are with additional predefined values like datetime.

Does anyone have ideas, sample code or suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You can test if something is an array with `Array.isArray(myVariable)`

Comment: json can't be BOTH an array and an object

Comment: I'm confused by the java tag.  Is the json actually coming from a java backend?

Comment: If you have NO idea how it's coming to you and the only thing you do know for certain is that each field will contain a colon (":"), then maybe regex all the values before and after the colon?   How is this Java related?

Comment: I could not understand what you need, do you want to turn this object into a string?

Comment: The object  coming in will definitely be a json object that could be a simple object or a larger json message. I will need to parse all the json fields or rather capture all fields and values to include into a new string.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand the end goal, but maybe its something like this

```
//  HTML
<div id="result">
  loading
</div>
//  CSS
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
}
//  JavaScript
window.handleJsonObj = function(json){
  let result = [
    'yourDate=' + Date.now() * 1000,
    'somethingElse=' + Math.random()
  ];
  Object.keys(json).forEach((key) => {
    let value = json[key];
    result.push(key + '=' + value)
  });
  let elem = document.getElementById('result');
  elem.innerHTML += 'measurement, ' + result.join(', ');
  elem.innerHTML += '<br><hr>'
};
window.parseJsonStr = function(jsonStr) {
    let json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    if (Array.isArray(json)) {
    return json[0];
  }
  return json;
}
$(document).ready(() => {
    let jsonString1 = '{"new_records":"1022", "updated_records":"546565", "changed_records":"546566", "deleted_records":"122345", "missing_records":"78"}';
  let jsonString2 = '[{"new_records":"1022", "updated_records":"546565", "changed_records":"546566", "deleted_records":"122345", "missing_records":"78"}]';
  let json1 = parseJsonStr(jsonString1);
  let json2 = parseJsonStr(jsonString2);
  window.handleJsonObj(json1);
  window.handleJsonObj(json2);
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/xpvt214o/501623/)

Comment: Thanks Rainer; that is functionally exactly what I wanted. I just needed to translate that into a format that would fit into a nifi environment